# Creating Whatsapp bot for removing idle members?

Tags: java, php, bots, chatbot, whatsapp

**Scenario**
i am in a test project to build a bot for a Whats App group which could analyze the members involvement status based on their post counts or their idleness for a while and it should remove such members if they continue to be idle for (say) 2 weeks.

**Question**
is it possible to create such a bot in PHP or else should i stick with java ? i don't want to use any third party API i like to code it from scratch. i need a suggestion to do this.

the reason i that i mentioned PHP is , there exists free PHP hosting online so there will not be a purchase of hosting for this small test project.